# How could Uchiha Madara suddently use a new Jutsu he never used before?

Tags: naruto

Well, I'm talking about the Senpo: Inton Raiha and the Senpo: Ranton Kouga.
To perform these two jutsus, one must have the Sage of the Six Paths senjutsu.
These are not common jutsus and I don't believe Madara has ever saw someone using them.

Comment: He can use it because Kishimoto taught him to. :P

Comment: This would be a case of "recieving Godly powers". You don't need practice or knowledge forehand to use a certain technique. The newly got powers introduce their moves to the user themselves.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin       What you said there seems to be pretty logic, but when you think about it , Sasuke did receive the same powers, and yet he was very surprised by his new Rinnegan abilities. Even Madara was,whereas he should have known that technique.

Comment: @Tobi: more light can be shed on this topic if you provide references. That way, providing factual descriptions or elucidating will become much easier.

Comment: He copied Hasiramas justu because kabuto altered his body and placed Hasiramas cells. That's The Only reason he was able to do wood style.You cannot copy kekki genkais just by using visual prowess!

Comment: power of hax eyes :v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I would like to quote this from wiki:

#### Intelligence of Madara Uchiha

> Madara's years of experience on the battlefield honed his strategic
>   ingenuity. He could quickly devise a number of approaches and could
>   switch approaches immediately. He could form and verify any theories
>   he comes up with using small details. In addition to his sheer
>   adaptability, **Madara was knowledgeable on a large variety of individuals and abilities, and thus could identify techniques when used and react with the most appropriate counter to them**.

Means he was knowledgeable and he was having so much of knowledge that he can perform various types of technique by simply observing them. There is no doubt that he was one of the kind with such a great observation skills.

There also one point which is worth noticing that :

> Madara do not use certain techniques more than once

Also you may think that performing those technique it take more than 1 year of practice before it can be use in real fight. But Madara has large chakra reserves which allowed him to fight nonstop for twenty-four hours before collapsing. He was skilled in chakra control as he could perform complicated techniques with a single hand seal. This is partly because he inherited Indra's chakra.

This point is also worth noticing which explains a little about how he can perform various technique :

> He is able to identify people and their powers by sensing their chakra
>   and masters the mightiest fire-based attacks in existence:
>   overwhelming streams of fire, gigantic clouds of searing ashes, and
>   powerful fireballs shaped like dragon heads, just to name a few

#### There are few more possible explanation which proves that Madara has some real observation skills :

1. > When Madara awakened his Sharingan as a child, with one tomoe in both
   >   eyes. With brief eye contact, Madara could place targets under
   >   genjutsu and paralyse them or **relay information**.

So while fighting he used to gather enough information about the technique which his opponent uses. You must also note that Madara was in so many fights so just think how much experience he is having.

2. > Madara and his brother Izuna were the first Uchiha to awaken the
   >   Mangekyō Sharingan. Madara knew about other users Mangekyō
   >   techniques, and was also capable of discerning the mechanics of these
   >   techniques with brief observation.

So he was able to learn all those techniques with brief observation.

3. > Madara Uchiha noted that the Sharingan can only be used to its full
   >   potential when both eyes are together.

This proves that he observe everything carefully.

After noticing all these points there is no doubt that Madara got some serious observation skills and also he always try to use new techniques every time. It might be true that he may have never known about few Jutsu and also he have never used it or seen it anywhere but he may have observed it and may have learned about that new Jutsu before he have tried it.

[image: For those who don't know who is Madara Uchiha]

Source -

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan

http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Madara_Uchiha

Comment: How would Madara learn his Sennin jutsu by mere observation when he was the only one to use Light Fang? Rikudou Naruto couldn't even use it..

Answer (score 0):

Remember back in early days of naruto when Kakashi was the "copy cat" ninja just because he had sharingan, and it was stated that the sharingan allowed a ninja to view another person's jutsu and copy it? Remember when Madara was reanimated with senju sage blood and could do hashirama's jutsu, despite not having the ability to ever do it before? I think generally madara could do any jutsu that he'd seen before, provided the conditions were met (proper amount of jutsu, proper control of natures, etc.), or at least that's my guess ;).

Comment: An answer with relevant links and references is much more valuable and definitely lends much more credibility, especially since your answer seems to be an opinion rather than an analysis.

Comment: While that might be true for Hashirama's case, Madara has never fought Rikudou Sennin, and thus there is no way he has ever seen Rikudou's jutsus, which means he has no chance of copying the jutsu.